# custom reports for ilias LMS

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a Learning Management system called Ilias  (http://www.ilias.de/).  I have a request from to generate a custom report that will break down all the users and the scores for each question.

Does any one know where I can find this information in the data base?  There is currently no database models built, so its difficult finding where I need to look for this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check [Ilias documentation](http://www.ilias.de/docu/repository.php?cmd=frameset&ref_id=581). Is it in german so I cannot help, but I'll suggest that you look for function calls that will allow you to make DataBase queries. This with a database structure will allow you or us to create a query to give you the desired info.

Some sistems are extensible and allow you to create modules, but I dont know if Ilias is one of them. Otherwise, as it seems to be Open Source, you can download and modify the system to deliver what you need.

Comment: The ILIAS dev-guide is available completely in english: https://www.ilias.de/docu/goto.php?target=lm_42&client_id=docu. There is a section about db access: https://www.ilias.de/docu/goto_docu_pg_25354_42.html. Further more and more of the documentation is factored out the the repo in git itself, see: https://github.com/ILIAS-eLearning/ILIAS/tree/trunk/docs

Answer (score 0):

This is very late. But in case other user consult this question it may help get a more complete answer. Other than the answer given above, you might find the following tables useful:

- usr_data (information about all existing users, you might use the global dic container in php to get information about the current logged-in user). E.g.:

  global $DIC;

  $DIC->user()->get...();
- tst_tests: To get information about all tests
- tst_mark: to get possible gradings by minimum_level
- tst_active: to get the runs by user
- tst_pass_result: to get the results by run
- ...

Whatever else you need.